# on IE9 xml response wraps the XML content in <span> and <div>

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-9, response

On ie9 ajax xml response is not getting as a XML object it returns as a text and xml contents are wraps in `<span>` and `<div>`. Even if my response content type is "text/xml".

ex:-

```
"<DIV class=e>< Span class=b>&nbsp;< /SPAN>< SPAN Class=m>&lt;?< /SPAN> <SPAN class=pi>xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"< /SPAN>< SPAN Class=m>&lt;?< /SPAN>< /DIV>"
```

such type of response is getting but i want actual XML Object. Please anyone know solution please help.